# Jquery binding number inputs doesn't work when increasing powers of ten (1000, 10000, 100000, etc.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, bind

I have two number inputs bound to each other that increment in 1000s, one is an upper range and one is a lower range. Whenever the lower range is set higher than the upper range, the upper range automatically changes 'value' and 'min' attribute to match the lower range value.

However, every time the upper range input reaches a power of ten threshold (9000, 90000, etc.) from increasing the lower range value, it just stops while the lower range is able to continue. Does anyone know why this is and how to stop this from happening?

https://jsfiddle.net/tg0ck5r1/

HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="upperBidRange" step="1000" >
<input type="number" id="lowerBidRange" step="1000" min="1000" value="1000">
```

JS:

```
function SetBidIncrementAmountAndUpperBidRangeMins() {
        $('#upperBidRange').attr('min', $('#lowerBidRange').val());
    }

function SetBidIncrementAmountAndUpperBidRangeValues() {
  $('#upperBidRange').val($('#lowerBidRange').val())
}

$(SetBidIncrementAmountAndUpperBidRangeMins);
$(SetBidIncrementAmountAndUpperBidRangeValues);

$('#lowerBidRange').bind('keyup mouseup onwheel input keypress change paste', function () {
  SetBidIncrementAmountAndUpperBidRangeMins();

  if ($('#lowerBidRange').val() > $('#upperBidRange').val()) {
    $(SetBidIncrementAmountAndUpperBidRangeValues);
  }
});
```

Comment: not able to understand the requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` *value* always stores a **String**, therefore `.val()` or `this.value` will always give you a String.
Doing `if (String > String) {` will not give you the desired cause you want numbers

Instead, use `parseInt(value, radix)` <sup>*[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)*</sup>

```
parseInt( $('#lowerBidRange').val() , 10 )
```

Here's how:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  // DOM is now ready and $ alias secured

  var $upper = $('#upperBidRange'),
      $lower = $('#lowerBidRange');

  function setUpperMin() {
    $upper.attr('min', $lower.val());
  }

  function setUpperVal() {
    $upper.val($lower.val());
  }

  setUpperMin();
  setUpperVal();

  $lower.on('input', function() {

    setUpperMin();

    var lowerVal = parseInt(this.value, 10),
        upperVal = parseInt($upper.val(), 10);

    if (lowerVal > upperVal) {
      setUpperVal();
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="upperBidRange" step="1000">UPPER
<br>
<input type="number" id="lowerBidRange" step="1000" min="1000" value="1000">LOWER
```

A simple variant would be using unary `+` *String→Number* conversion

```
  $lower.on('input', function() {

    setUpperMin();

    if (+this.value > +$upper.val()) {
      setUpperVal();
    }

  });
```